# How can I make scp support a globstar?

Tags: ssh, rsync, zsh, scp

Is there a clean way to make scp support a globstar, or do I need to do this with rsync?

`[garnett@cherry aips]$ ls **/ACN-2017-008_1977*.7z` works, after doing `shopt -s globstar` or using zsh

`[garnett@gate1 ~]$ scp cherry:/data/alder/aips/**/ACN-2017-008_1977*.7z .` doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to change the scp expansion rules server-side. Is it just unimplemented in sshd?

Comment: What is the error message you get? My first guess would be that the user's default shell on the remote machine is used. Can you change the for a test? Second, use single quotes so that the wildcard doesn't get expanded on the client: `scp cherry:'/data/alder/aips/**/ACN-2017-008_1977*.7z' .`

Comment: Success! I wasn't able to chsh to zsh on here because it's a network account set up in a special way, but adding `shopt -s globstar` to .bashrc on the remote and using single quotes for the command worked.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above -- the way to do this is to make sure that the login shell on the remote supports globstar, either by adding `shopt -s globstar` to the remote user's `~/.bashrc` or changing their default shell to `zsh`.